# My current bicycle is a 2010 Diamondback Response Sport. I like the frame and i am thinking to upgrade to a road bike, please advice?

Tags: diamondback

Is it a good idea to upgrade to:

- Novatec D042SB 26" Wheelset
- 2 x Schwalbe Marathon Racer Road Tyres for MTB (26"x1.50")
- Open to Deore / SLX groupset

Thanks in advance for your advice

Comment: Changing the tires makes sense. Why change the wheels and groupset?

Comment: The D042SB is just a rear hub as far as I can tell: https://www.novatecusa.net/product/d042sb-ss-11s/

Comment: Marathon Racer is a terrible tire. Check bicyclerollingresistance.com for better choices

Answer (score 4):

The Diamondback Response Sport appears to be an entry-level mountain bike, retailing at up to US$400 at the time of writing. [The 2010 model](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/21608/) should have had an 8s triple drivetrain and front suspension.

I'll assume the OP is thinking about upgrading the same bike to be more capable on the road, as opposed to upgrading to a road bike. The question body asks about upgrading to slick 26" tires and a 1x12 MTB groupset.

I suspect that a lot of people buying entry-level bikes think that they might ride on some off-road trails, but in practice they are mainly on paved roads or light off-road trails. By the latter, I mean things like crushed limestone trails or dirt roads that are a hard surface, little loose gravel, no big rocks or roots, mainly straight paths.

A lot of consumers probably see suspension forks and think that these make a better bike. The issue is that on paved surfaces or the sort of light off-road surfaces that I described above, cheap suspension is more of a liability than a benefit. Suspension requires maintenance. If you don't do maintenance, eventually the suspension will fail, and you will now be worse off than if you had bought a bike with a rigid front fork. Meanwhile, a lot of suspension is available through your tires.

As @DavidD said in comments, it would be fine to change to slick tires. If you wanted a more road-going bike, it would be optimal to have bought that from the start, e.g. a flat bar rigid hybrid with slick tires.

It is generally not cost-effective to make major overhauls to the components of entry-level bikes. A Deore groupset alone probably retails for a comparable price to the entire bike, plus you have to install it or pay someone else to do so. Naturally, you could upgrade the components for sentimental reasons. However, it is more cost-effective to buy a bike closer to your own needs, and you'd probably find that bike to be a major upgrade as well. So, I would first think about what you want the bike to do - and because you are asking the question, the answer is probably not something where you need a hardtail MTB to navigate.

Comment: Concur - start with road-oriented tyres, which can be reverted easily before dropping serious cash on a drivetrain change.   Tyres are consumables anyway.